# What is the exact difference between mongod and mongos

Tags: mongodb

While I was looking into the MongoDB documentation, I found two different terms `mongod` and `mongos`.

While starting the server, I am using `./mongod --dbpath <path to mongodb>` and I am running `./mongo` to connect to the server.

Can someone please clarify the differences between these two terms.

Answer (score 58):

`mongod` is the daemon, `mongo` is the client, `mongos` is the 'MongoDB Shard Utility'. Take a look at `man mongos`:

> mongos  for  "MongoDB  Shard," is a routing service for MongoDB shard configurations that processes queries from the application layer, and determines the location of this data in
>          the sharded cluster, in order to complete these operations.  From the perspective of the application, a mongos instance behaves identically to any other MongoDB instance.

Answer (score 24):

The core components in the MongoDB package are: **mongod** - the core database process; **mongos** -  the controller and query router for sharded clusters; and **mongo** the interactive MongoDB Shell.

For more information http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/

Answer (score 19):

**Mongos** = MongoDB Shard Utility, the controller and query router for sharded clusters. Sharding partitions the data-set into discrete parts.

**Mongod** = The primary daemon process for the MongoDB system. It handles data requests, manages data access, and performs background management operations.

This explanation of mongo replication and sharding really helped me understand it: https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53705/106925

Answer (score 2):

- [**mongod**](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongod/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongod)
  is the daemon (which is why a `d` at the end) that takes care of all the heavy lifting e.g. accepting and serving the data requests and performing management tasks in the background.
- [**mongos**](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/program/mongos/#mongodb-binary-bin.mongos)
  is a query router that routes the application queries to appropriate shards.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In shard clusters, mongod as a shard data process and store shard metadata process. mongos as a route process to manipulate client request.