# How to enable sharding in shard collections in mongodb using Python?

Tags: python, json, mongodb, relational-database, pymongo

Currently, I am using a bash-script in order to enable sharding for DB and then shard collection.
I am using eval:

```
mongo <ip_host> --eval "sh.enableSharding(<name_db>)
```

and then, surprise, shard collection:

```
mongo <ip_host> --eval "sh.shardCollection("<db_name>.<collection>", {shardKey : 1})"
```

I am trying to do the same, but from Python using pymongo lib.
I have some ideas:

```
client = pymongo.MongoClient()
client.admin.command('enableSharding', db_name)    
client.admin.command('shardCollection', f'{db_name}.{collection}), key=shard_key)
```

or using eval:

```
db_name.eval("sh.enableSharding", collection)
db_name.eval("sh.shardCollection", collection)
```

But neither of these methods work.
Is there anything you could suggest or should I use os.system() to call bash-scripting from Python?

Comment: In general, the `mongo` shell is the command line tool to be used for all administrative actions. The drivers are mostly used for application development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command `client.admin.command('enableSharding', db_name)` is correct; however it [can only be run against a `mongos` instance](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/enableSharding/#dbcmd.enableSharding); I suspect you are trying to run it against a `mongod` instance.

Comment: could you please make it clarify - what is the difference between mongo, mongos and mogod?
I am trying to use that code on AWS instances, if it might assist

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364778/what-is-the-exact-difference-between-mongod-and-mongos